# Error The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Open Class, Show Error Log)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, android-cardview

I am using eclipse software
How to fix it i have no idea

[image: Error image android.support.v7.widget.CardView in eclipse]

[image: Used Plugins image android.support.v7.widget.CardView]

Comment: show your gradle app file

Comment: show is your gradle , and the code you are using for the cardview

Comment: Add your app gradle file

Answer (score 0):

forgot eclipe use studio and try with  this dependencies in your project `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

to import `cardview` in Eclipse (via Import->Existing Android Code into Workspace) is located in your

> Android SDK folder: Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\cardview